# Comparing pefromance between HTML5 and Flash app

Tags: flash, html

For research reasons, I've built "identical" HTML5 app and Flash app. I need an effective method (hopefully software) to test and later compare system performance.

Comment: 1) They are *not* identical.  They just might serve the same use case. 2) What you *should* compare is how many platforms does the app run on, how long it took you to write it, how much time you spent fixing problems for browser X and what that meant for production value. 3) Check out Selenium and its Flex Pilot plugin. http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way of doing this would be `trace()` in case of Actionscript and `console.log()` in case of HTML5/JS.

You can use `new Date().time` for AS3 and `new Date().getTime()` for JS.

So you can print start time and end time and compare them, or you can 'ask' your application to do the math (`taskTime = endTime - startTime`).
The drawback of using `trace` in Flash is that it requires debug version of the player which is a little bit slower than the normal version.

Answer (score 2):

Stats for flash
https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats
Stats for JS
https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/

Don't bother, Flash is faster anytime.